# expo- react native : there is way to see the content of the expo FileSystem and also delete content from there?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

there is way to see the content of the FileSystem and also delete content from there?

i have data inside the expo FileSystem and i need :

1. look inside FileSystem because i dont know how to find this file because i work with the expo client sdk with the qr code scan and i dont understand how can i find this file there .
2. i want to know how to delete contents from the file system .
3. how can i see the sqlite database as a real table ?

this is my examle :

```
saveDbData = async () => {
    const { data, isLoaded } = this.state;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const mediaData = data[i];
      const dbResult = await insertPlace(
        mediaData.artist,
        mediaData.image,
        mediaData.title,
        mediaData.url
      );
      console.log("SQL", `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}/SQLite/places.db`);
    }
    const fetchawesome = await fetchPlaces();
    console.log(fetchawesome)
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are three questions from your part, I'll try to answer them one by one and provide a possible solution.

> look inside FileSystem because i dont know how to find this file
>   because i work with the expo client sdk with the qr code scan and i
>   dont understand how can i find this file there .

You can access the file system using the `FileSystem` package from `expo`. Here's how you can do it. Import the package first.

```
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
```

Then you can find the `URI` of the file like this.

```
const { uri } = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(
    `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/${"yourDB.db"}`
  );
```

> I want to know how to delete contents from the file system.

You can delete a file if you have access to its location or `URI`. This is how you can delete it. It returns a promise.

```
FileSystem.deleteAsync(fileUri)
```

> how can I see the SQLite database as a real table?

This is a tricky part because since you're using your android phone to run the application via `expo`, you won't have direct access to your `db`. One thing you can do is to move the `db` to someplace else where you have access to and using the `Sharing` API from `expo` to save or send the `db` to yourself via email or any other way.

```
 import * as Sharing from "expo-sharing"; 

 let documenturi = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}/yourDB.db`;
  await FileSystem.copyAsync({
    from: uri,
    to: documenturi,
  });
  Sharing.shareAsync(documenturi);
```

You can make this as a function which fire's on a `Button` press on you can even put this in `useEffect` or lifecycle methods to fire up when the screen loads.